# Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations when define delegate

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, delegates

I want to define `delegate` as the following:

```
public delegate void DataRequestingEventHandler(object sender, 
CommandEventArgs e) where Entity : IEntityId<EntityKey>, new() where 
EntityKey : IEntityKey, new();
```

But I am receiving this error:

> Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations.  So you need to add [Generic Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) to your declaration to make it a generic declaration.

Looks like you intended `Entity` and `EntityKey` to be generic type parameters, but failed to declare them.  Also by convention generic type parameters start with `T`, eg:

```
public delegate void DataRequestingEventHandler<TEntity, TEntityKey>(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
    where TEntity : IEntityId<TEntityKey>, new() where TEntityKey : IEntityKey, new();
```